# Controlling for Price Elasticity Bias in Causal Model

Tags: causality, causalimpact

I am trying to study the treatment effect of lowering prices on sales (demand). My treatment includes 3 difference price points ($10, $12, $14) and sales is a continuous $ variable. All buyers have full price transparency, meaning they see that similar items are priced at different price points, thus trying to exploit the lowest price.

When I look at my ATE, it is evident that the lower the prices, the higher the demand (up to some point). However, I want to understand the price buyers would have paid in the absence of price transparency to maximize revenue. I have tried using EconMl's DRPolicyTree model which I defined as:

```
est = DRPolicyTree(
    categories='auto',  
    honest=True, 
    max_depth=3,    model_propensity=model_propensity=RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1,class_weight='balanced',random_state=0),
    model_regression=RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1, random_state=0),
    random_state=0
)
est.fit(Y=Y, T=T, X=X, W=None)
```

Y=sales price per unit $, T=(offer 1/control: $10, offer 2: $12, offer 3: $14), X=bunch of covariates, W=No Confounder

Again, when running this model, my ATE is very skewed towards lower price points because buyers try to buy as cheap as possible but with this model, I thought I would get counterfactual estimates of price (i.e. what would buyers pay under different/higher price points)? Somehow this is not working.  What would be the reason?

When printing DRPolicyTree.predict_proba(X_test), I get this output (from the model_propensity:

```
array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.]])
```

When I print output from model_regression, I get:

```
array([[[ -670.44733164, -1023.21580196,   -89.90563908, ]],..
```

1. Am I using the wrong model framework? Why is the counterfactual estimates showing that most inventory should be prices at the lowest price?
2. Am I not adding the buyer bias as either covariate or confounder? If so, what is a good way to add it?
3. Do I need to preprocess my data to account for this bias?